# How to refer JS files like componenet and use acrsoss the web application

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, javascript-objects

I have one image editor and it has lot of JS files. 
asp.net empty project containing all JS files that required for that editor.

Now, I want to keep these all JS at some common place and refer to any project so, in case any changes then it could apply directly.

I was thinking to refer this asp.net empty project assembly to any other web application and refer JS file (though not sure how to refer JS from one asp.net application to other web application).

What is the best way to keep all JS at common place and refer to web application project and use like some component.

thanks

Comment: Well I assume you are using visual studio - 2017 and 2015 have support for the "bundler minifier", which can compile and minify all files into one (Css and JS) as for using JS across multiple projects it sounds like you will need some form of source control - GIT for example. Let me know if you need some help with bundler minifier.